# Dockerfile ENV variable substitution into another ENV variable

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am learning Docker and facing issue in substituting the value of one env variable into another env variable.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu

ENV var_env=Tarun

ENV command="echo Hello $var_env"

CMD ["sh","-c","echo Hello $var_env"]
```

Now, after building it with tag name "exp", then

```
sudo docker run -e  "var_env=New Env Value" exp
```

It gives me correct output as

```
Hello New Env Value
```

But, if I see the environment variables associated by executing

```
sudo docker run -e  "var_env=New Env Value" exp env
```

It gives me this output:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=138aa8852d8d
var_env=New Env Value
command=echo Hello Tarun
HOME=/root
```

In it, the value of `var_env` environment variable is changed and value of `command` environment variable remains same.

I need to find a way so that if I change the value of `var_env` environment variable by the above command, it will update the value of `var_env` environment variable inside `command` environment variable also.

For reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement

Comment: That's what I'd expect - you're setting a *value* in the environment variable, not some kind of function.

Comment: If the answer solved your question please accept it or provide additional information to further debug the issue at hand. If you have already found a solution please post it and accept it to share it with the community

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option 1: at container start**

You can use a wrapper script to create your environment variables with the inheritance that you wish. Here is a simple wrapper script

wrapper.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# prep your environement variables
export command="echo Hello $var_env"

# run your actual command
echo "Hello $command"
```

Your dockerfile needs to be adapted to use it

```
FROM ubuntu
COPY ./wrapper.sh .
ENV var_env=Tarun
ENV command="echo Hello $var_env"
CMD ["sh","-c","./wrapper.sh"]
```

---

**Option 2: during build**

You can archive this by rebuilding your image with different build args.
Lets keep your dockerfile almost the same:

```
FROM ubuntu
ARG var_env=Tarun
ENV command="echo Hello $var_env"
CMD ["sh","-c","echo Hello $var_env"]
```

and run

```
docker build -t test .
```

this gives you your default image as defined in your dockerfile, but your **var_env** is no longer an environment variable.

next we run

```
docker build -t test --build-arg var_env="New Env Value" .
```

this will invalidate the docker cache only from the line in which you have defined your build arg. So keep your definition of your ARG close to where it is used in order to maximize the caching functionality of docker build.

You can find more about build args here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

Comment: Clemens, This works. But, I can't pass the value of "var_env" as --build-arg. Because I need to pass this value at run time, so that I can run my image in different environments. For demo purpose, I have written var_env=Tarun. While passing at docker run time, I will override it and it will have values of dev,qa etc and appropriately, I need to update the "command" environment variable.

Comment: Tarun, then you will need to go the "hard" way and write a wrapper script that sets your environments based on your hierarchy on startup since you such a hierarchy as you have described does not work with environment variable under Linux (not just docker). If you like I can create an example wrapper for you.

Comment: Clemens, after trying your first option, I am able to update the "command" variable and I can execute my command inside wrapper script. But, If I exec into the container and do "echo $command", I am still getting "echo Hello Tarun" and not "echo Hello New Env Value". Is it a way around to address this also?

Comment: Why do you need that? From your wrapper script, you would also start your application. Therefore your application would have access to the environment variables set in the wrapper script. Isn't that what you need?

Comment: Correct Clemens, your approach is helpful and working for me. But, I am asking if there is a way around to make it such that everywhere "command" variable is updated.

Comment: how do connect to your container? if you run `docker exec -it NAME bash` you will create a new shell process in the container which you connect to. That is a new process and does not relate at all to what happened in the wrapper.sh shell with PID 1. I assume there is a way to alter the environment variables for any new shell that is gets spawned in your container - just like any shell on your host server. You would need to check that